# Can a WP Rewrite Rule Filter query multiple Post Types?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I currently have setup a simple rewrite rule in the theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', function($rules) {
    $newRules  = array(
        '(.+)/?$'   => 'index.php?my_post_type=$matches[1]'
    );
    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
});
```

I also have my permalinks set to somewhat default in settings:

```
Custom Structure: /%postname%
```

The rewrite works perfect, as it should. However, my question is :

**Is it possible to allow this redirect rule to default to the 'page' post-type where it cannot find a matching post in 'my_post_type' post-type?**

From what I understand, the rewrite rule only looks for the specified post type and then returns a 404 when not found. I would still like a 404, but only if both (in order) 'my_post_type' AND 'page' post-types don't have a post with that slug.

I searched and found some alternate (hacky) solutions, but could not find a recent or quite relevant question. Thanks!